# How did Obi-Wan Know About Yoda?

Tags: star-wars, the-empire-strikes-back, obi-wan-kenobi, yoda

The scene where Luke sees Ben's force ghost, Ben tells him to go to the Dagobah system and seek out Yoda, the Jedi master who trained him.

How did Ben know about Yoda though? The remaining Jedi went into exile after Order 66 and the two of them likely wouldn't have stayed in touch due to likely being found by the Empire.

So how did Obi-Wan know Yoda's location?

Comment: Yoda told him dude. I thought this was common knowledge.

Comment: Can you find the quote where he tells him? :)

Comment: He literally tells him he's going to go hide on Dagobah near the end of Episode 3.

Comment: Well... they can contact AFTER DEATH with one significant being in the whole galaxy... what makes you think they cannot do something similar while they are alive?

Comment: @Probst I don't see that in [the script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-Revenge-of-the-Sith.html). It would be logical, however.

Comment: I swear he says that's where he's going to Obi-Wan and Bail Organa after Organa picks him up from the fight with Sideous but I can't check right now so I could be wrong I suppose.

Comment: Ben and Yoda are in contact with each other; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i3jI3RrMsVI&feature=youtu.be&t=1m37s

Comment: @Probst: in that scene, Yoda told Bail that he failed and has to go into exile, but he didn't say where.  But, given that Yoda specifically tells Obi-Wan to go to Tatooine, and that he has more training for him (to learn to commune with Qui-Gon), Yoda is clearly in contact with Obi-Wan for awhile after RotS ends, so Yoda could easily have told Obi-Wan off-screen that he was going to Dagobah.

Comment: Um,  you do realize not every piece of dialog between two characters can be shown in a two-hour movie, right?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### It's likely that [Yoda](http://starwarsrebels.wikia.com/wiki/Yoda) actually *did* keep in touch.

We can't say for sure that Yoda did or did not stay in touch, given that the new canon that's currently being written, but Yoda has been shown to be quite capable of contacting people via the Force.

Moreover, we don't know what exactly happened after the end of Revenge of the Sith; Yoda claims that he will teach Obi Wan how to commune with Qui-Gon:

> The secret of the Ancient Order of the Whills, he studied. How to commune with him. I will teach you.

and, given Kenobi's success in becoming a Force Ghost, it can be assumed that this spirit speaking training was successful.  We then have a 16 year gap between this point and A New Hope, wherein we learn (in the above video) that Yoda has the ability to keep in touch. Thus, it can be assumed that at some point Yoda either met with Obi-Wan or contacted him through other means.

Comment: Thanks for this! My theories were that as a force ghost Obi-Wan was able to travel prettymuch anywhere and was able to find Yoda at that point and relay to Luke where to find him. I was also thinking that they wouldn't keep in touch as Vader would feel a disturbance in the force and would find them.

Comment: @RyanJ That's also a possibility, though I think they'll probably put the two of them together at some point before ANH. Perhaps in Rebels.

Comment: @RyanJ Why don't you partake of some Star Wars my man? Then you would know.

Answer (score 3):

The junior novelisation for Revenge of the Sith indicates that they **both left the Tantive IV at much the same time, one setting course for Tatooine, the other en route to Dagobah.** Although it's not made explicitly clear, it seems vanishingly unlikely that Yoda would keep his destination a secret.

> Once the funeral was over, Bail Organa set his cruiser on a carefully
> planned course to Alderaan. Shortly after the ship left Naboo, it
> flung two small escape pods in opposite directions along the Outer
> Rim. One carried Jedi Master Yoda toward the uninviting and
> uninhabited swamp planet of Dagobah; the other carried Jedi Master
> Obi-Wan Kenobi and a wailing infant boy in the direction of Tatooine.
> The girl, as planned, went on to Alderaan, to be raised as a princess
> by Bail Organa and his wife, the queen of Alderaan. She was joined by
> the droids R2-D2 and C-3PO.
>
> <sub><sup>[Revenge of the Sith - Junior Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_III:_Revenge_of_the_Sith_(junior_novelization))</sup></sub>

On top of that, when Ben turns up to advise Luke about going to visit Yoda, it would appear that (as a Force ghost) he's already **perfectly well able to contact Yoda and make sure that he hasn't relocated.**